# Why to deposit more ETH than the gas fee when minting?

Tags: mint

I try to mint on SuperRare and when I push the button Mint I get a system message that I should deposit more ETH, altough there is 4x amount of ETH in my SR wallet than the estimated amount needed for the gas fee. What additional fees may emerge?